# Use a custom DNS resolver in the Glide that uses OkHttp3

Tags: android, dns, android-glide, okhttp

I used Glide(3.7.0) with OkHttp3(3.6.0) as the image loader in my Android application and want to use a custom DNS resolver instead of the default.

> The GlideModule:

```
public class GlideMod implements GlideModule{
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    }
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .dns(new HttpDns())// Inject here
                .build();
        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory=new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);
        glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,factory);
    }
}
```

> The HttpDns:

```
public class HttpDns implements Dns {
    private static final Dns SYSTEM = Dns.SYSTEM;

    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> lookup(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        Log.d("HackDns","lookup ["+hostname+"]");

        return SYSTEM.lookup(hostname);
    }
}
```

The log did not output, proving that the custom dns resolver did not work at all. So, how can i do.

Comment: Are you printing debug logs? Try `Log.i` instead?

Comment: It should work. maybe something went wrong with the logger, restart you Android Studio and retry.